# Cropping GeoTIFF on BBOX edge with GDAL in server

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I want to crop a large GeoTIFF on the edge of the bbox which is given in latitude and longitude:

```
bbox = (26.8040970,46.5625741,26.6225059,46.2075912)
```

When I use the following code:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr

root = '/var/www/html/py/'

bbox = (26.8040970,46.5625741,26.6225059,46.2075912)
gdal.Translate(root+'cut_tiff/output_crop_raster.tif', root+'tiff/phh2o.tif', projWin = bbox)
```

I have the following error:

> ERROR 1: Error: Computed -srcwin 2095 1815 -182 355 has negative width
> and/or height.

When displaying the information:

> gdal.Info

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /var/www/html/py/tiff/phh2o.tif
Size is 5032, 4997
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
     DATE["WGS_1984",
         SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
             AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
         AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
     GET["Greenwich",0],
     UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
     AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (24.708252026038561,48.378145004703761)
Pixel Size = (0.000999947922878,-0.001000009407526)
Metadata:
   AREA_OR_POINT=Area
   TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
   TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=72
   TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=72
Image Structure Metadata:
   COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
   INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left ( 24.7082520, 48.3781450) ( 24d42'29.71"E, 48d22'41.32"N)
Lower Left ( 24.7082520, 43.3810980) ( 24d42'29.71"E, 43d22'51.95"N)
Upper Right ( 29.7399900, 48.3781450) ( 29d44'23.96"E, 48d22'41.32"N)
Lower Right ( 29.7399900, 43.3810980) ( 29d44'23.96"E, 43d22'51.95"N)
Center ( 27.2241210, 45.8796215) ( 27d13'26.84"E, 45d52'46.64"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the order for [projwin](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-projwin) wants to be: upper left x, upper left y, lower right x, lower right y; so you will want:

`bbox = (26.6225059,46.5625741,26.8040970,46.2075912)`